# Why am I not able to correctly calculate the median survival time for the Weibull distribution?

Tags: survival, median, weibull-distribution

The survival function for the Weibull distribution is:

$S(t) = exp(-\lambda t^\alpha)$, $\lambda$ = scale parameter, $\alpha$ = shape parameter

If I wanted to calculate the median survival time, I would set $S(t) = 0.5$. Rearranging terms, this means the median survival time would be calculated as follows:

$t_{median} = (\frac{-log(0.5)}{\lambda})^{(1/\alpha)}$

Let's say I set $\lambda = 3$ and $\alpha = 2$. Then the median survival time is clearly:

$t_{median} = (\frac{-log(0.5)}{3})^{(1/2)} = 0.481$

However, when I do a sanity check on this and run this in R, the median survival for a Weibull distribution with scale = 3 and shape = 2 is clearly not 0.481 and is more like 2.5:

```
Time <- sort(rweibull(1000, shape = 2, scale = 3))
Time[500]
```

Any time I run this code, I am getting somewhere right around 2.5, +/- 0.1 or so. But definitely nowhere near 0.481.

So what do I have wrong here? Why is the actual median time for simulated data nowhere near the theoretical median time?

Comment: I get a different survival function: $S(t) = \exp(-(t/\lambda)^\alpha)$ and hence the median survival time is $\lambda\log(2)^{(1/\alpha)}$. With $\lambda = 3, \alpha = 2$ this evaluates to $2.49766$ as you found using simulation. This is what the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) article lists under "Median".

Comment: As always with these things, when you get a discrepancy, check the parameterization being used is identical.

Answer (score 5):

You got trapped in the thicket of multiple parameterizations of the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Second_alternative).

In what Wikipedia calls the "[standard parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Standard_parameterization)", the survival function  with scale parameter $\lambda$ and shape parameter $\alpha$ is:

$$S(t)=\exp(-(t/\lambda)^\alpha). $$

That's the parameterization used by `rweibull()`. In that parameterization, the median is $\lambda(\ln 2)^{(1/\alpha)}$, which for $\lambda= 3$ and $\alpha = 2$ gives:

```
3*(log(2)^(1/2))
# [1] 2.497664
```

presumably close to the value that you found by simulation.

You seem to be using what Wikipedia calls the "[first alternative parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#First_alternative)."